# Dependency injection and inversion of control in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty familiar with dependency injection and inversion of control in various languages and as concepts. I cannot however get my head around achieving a pattern like the following example using AngularJS best practices.

I'm trying to create an object registry in which objects can be added and fetched later by a key.

```
function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sample')
        .service('ObjectRegistry', function () {
            var members = [];

            this.addMember = function(key, object) { 
                members[key] = object;
            }

            this.getMember = function(key) {
                return members[key] || {};
            }
        })
        .service('ObjectInstance', [ 'ObjectRegistry', function (ObjectRegistry) {

            this.doSomething = function () {};

            ObjectRegistry.addMember("my-key", this);
        }])
        .controller('MyController', [ 'ObjectRegistry', function (ObjectRegistry) {

    // Here I need to get ObjectRegistry populated with all services that register themselves in the registry, in this example, with ObjectInstance under the key "my-key"

        });

}(angular));
```

The issue is that ObjectRegistry is never populated since ObjectInstance is never initialized (and I do not want to have to do from the controller).

What would be the best approach to achieve this in Angular ? I'm familiar for example with Symfony's DI container and compiler passes that allow to replicate this pattern, but I'm not too sure of how to go at it with Angular's DI.

Comment: Why would you want a second registry?

Comment: Many reasons, current use case is something similar to a plugin registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for posterity, I finally managed to find a solution that suits my needs by using the config phase and a service provider:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sampleApp', [])
        .provider("ObjectRegistry", function () {
            var objects = {};

            return {
                bind: function (name, object) { objects[name] = object; },
                $get: function () {
                    return {
                        get: function (name) { return objects[name]; }
                    };
                }
            };
        });
}(angular));
```

And wherever else in my code:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sampleApp')
        .config(function (ObjectRegistryProvider) {
            ObjectRegistryProvider.bind("my-key", { });
        });
}(angular));
```